# POJO class from JSON for Retrofit2 Callback

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2, pojo

```
{
   "success":true,
   "userobject":{
       "username":"user",
       "email":"user@gmail.com",
       "password":"user123"
    }
}
```

This is my JSON. I want to create POJO class from this. Now i have something like this:

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

I want access to fields like "username", "email", "password" in Retrofit Callback:

```
 final LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(email, password);
        Call<LoginResponse> call = service.login(loginRequest);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response)
            {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    background.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_login_screen);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.body().getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

And it doesn't work. I can access to "success" field of course only. How it POJO class should look like?

Comment: The response data is retrieved by calling [`Response.body()`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#body--).

Comment: Yes i have response.body() but i couldn't access to username, email and password fields

Comment: You're accessing it here: `response.body().getEmail()`. If there's a problem with the result, please clarify. Don't make us guess what your question is.

Comment: It's effect of how JSON object is build. Fields username, email and password are in "userobject" and i can't access there. I should biuld POJO class better but i don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

userObject is a new object, you should create a new class to access it:

```
public class LoginResponse {
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;

    private UserObject userobject;


    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public UserObject getUserObject() {
       return userobject;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class UserObject {
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```